# Raspberry pico cannot compile due to Nmake error

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2019, nmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I was trying setup enviorment to develop some program for new PICO, but only compile one time, after I haved this error:

```
[main] Building folder: pico-examples 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/pico/pico-examples/build --config Debug --target blink --
[build] Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
[build] [  0%] Built target bs2_default
[build] [  0%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[build] [  0%] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[build] 
[build] Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29337.0
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build] [100%] Built target elf2uf2
[build] [  0%] No install step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[build] [  0%] Completed 'ELF2UF2Build'
[build] [  0%] Built target ELF2UF2Build
[build] Scanning dependencies of target blink
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target blink
[build] blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\compiler_depend.make(4) : fatal error U1033: syntax error : ':' unexpected
[build] Stop.
[build] NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\Nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
[build] Stop.
[build] NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\Nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
[build] Stop.
[build] NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\Nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
[build] Stop.
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

The blink application that I´m compiling it´s standart example from Raspberry SDK:

```
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

int main() {
    const uint LED_PIN = 25;
    gpio_init(LED_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(LED_PIN, GPIO_OUT);
    while (true) {
        gpio_put(LED_PIN, 1);
        sleep_ms(250);
        gpio_put(LED_PIN, 0);
        sleep_ms(250);
    }
}
```

I´ve installed VS code already and after installed VS 2019 for this PICO. I followed step by step the documentation from Raspberry(getting started with Raspberry PICO). Also started by Command prompt from VS2019.

I have tried to install separetlly last Windows SDK, also I reinstalled Visual Studio. but still same.

Someone can help me on this topic? I cant sleep with this issue :(

Autogenerated file what its the problem example:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "NMake Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.20

blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\include\pico\critical_section.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\include\pico\lock_core.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\types.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\machine\_default_types.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\features.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\_newlib_version.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\_intsup.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\_stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stdbool.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stddef.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-examples\build\generated\pico_base\pico\version.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\config.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-examples\build\generated\pico_base\pico\config_autogen.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\boards\include\boards\pico.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync
...

blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\types.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\_intsup.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\_stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stdbool.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-examples\build\generated\pico_base\pico\version.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\config.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-examples\build\generated\pico_base\pico\config_autogen.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\boards\include\boards\pico.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\float_init_rom.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_platform\include\pico\platform.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float.
...
.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\machine\_default_types.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\features.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\_newlib_version.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\_intsup.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\_stdint.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\stdio.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\_ansi.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\newlib.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\config.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\machine\ieeefp.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\cdefs.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stddef.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\10.2.1\include\stdarg.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\C_\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\printf.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\reent.h

blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_platform\include\pico\platform.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\cdefs.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\types.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_regs\include\hardware\platform_defs.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_regs\include\hardware\regs\addressmap.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\assert.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\assert.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\_ansi.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\newlib.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\sys\config.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: c\:\progra~2\gnuarm~1\102020~1\arm-none-eabi\include\machine\ieeefp.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include\pico\error.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_stdio\include\pico\stdio.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_time\include\pico\time.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_timer\include\hardware\timer.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_structs\include\hardware\structs\timer.h
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\blink.c.obj: C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\ha
C:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_vreg\vreg.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_vreg\vreg.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_vreg\include\hardware\vreg.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_structs\include\hardware\structs\vreg_and_chip_reset.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_regs\include\hardware\regs\vreg_and_chip_reset.h:

C:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_watchdog\watchdog.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_watchdog\watchdog.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_structs\include\hardware\structs\watchdog.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_regs\include\hardware\regs\watchdog.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_structs\include\hardware\structs\psm.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_regs\include\hardware\regs\psm.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_xosc\xosc.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_stdio_uart\stdio_uart.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_bootrom\bootrom.c:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_bootrom\include\pico\bootrom.h:

C\:\pico\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_double\double_init_rom.c:
```

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error is stated: `[build] blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\compiler_depend.make(4) : fatal error U1033: syntax error : ':' unexpected` so you have a typo in your code. Please include the code so that users may see what is causing the error.

Comment: @fth: Not likely. The file where the error occurs is auto-generated, so shouldn't contain any syntax errors. I'd try a clean build.

Comment: Yes, I updated with the File auto generated content , thanks for help

Comment: No problem @NachFenix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, solution was erease the content from autogenerated file, save file and build again...,

After several builds error appear again, and same procedure was success :D

Thanks all that tried to helped me if knows about root issue will be great!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem myself trying to compile in VS Code, the first pass works fine any recompiles fail with the same error.

The cause of the error are the compiler_depend.make files containing incorrectly escaped paths. It is trying to escape the : after the Windows drive letter. It does not do this though to the first entry in each section though that entry is duplicated with the incorrect path as the second entry in each section.

For example

```
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\D_\projects\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: D\:\projects\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c
```

Should be

```
blink\CMakeFiles\blink.dir\D_\projects\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c.obj: D:\projects\pico\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\critical_section.c
```

The current quick fix I have so far is to a replace "\:" with ":"  in all compiler_depend.make files

Comment: @NachFenixI have since found it the root cause, itapears the release candidate of CMake 3.20.0 is at fault. I uninstalled this and installed CMakle 3.19.6 and found the initial build and rebuilding in VC works 100% with no errors. The bad escaping of file paths is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the already mentionned solution (deleting the contents of /build) as a rebuild DOS command for those not too savvy with it. Run it from the build folder.

`del /q /s * && cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" && nmake`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current CMAKE version nd install the version 3.20 from here:
https://cmake.org/files/v3.20/

Do not forget to add CMAKE to path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).